# Can't Connect External Stylesheet to HTML

Tags: html, css

This will be an easy question for you to answer. I'm making a Google Clone Homepage, and I'm trying to connect my **CSS** and **HTML**. For some reason it isn't working.

My **HTML** and **CSS** are in the same folder so that's not the problem. In my **HTML** sheet, I've already linked to the external **CSS** stylesheet as well. The **HTML** code is below.

```
<style> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="googleduplicate.css"/>
</style>
```

I'm expecting to see my **HTML** change because of my **CSS**, but I don't see that.

You can find my full **HTML** code: https://codeshare.io/ay3yrw

And full **CSS** here: https://codeshare.io/GABLnN

Comment: Don't wrap your <link> element in a <style>.

Comment: First, remove the `<style> ... </style>` tag from the `header`. Now, you css will not be applied completely because your HTML and CSS are totally wrong. For example, you are styling in the **CSS** file `.top left links {...}`. Here `top` supposed to be a `class` but you defined it as an `id` in this line ` <div id="top left links">`. Moreover, an `id` should be unique. Change `id` with `class` Now, the css must be  `.top.left.links {...}` without white spaces.

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, in the question itself, don't make us go off site to find important information. Preferably include your code as a [mcve].

Comment: A link element should not be wrapped in a style tag, this prevents it from working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check your code and I found three main reasons why your **CSS** doesn't work properly.

#### 1. `link` tag

As many others mentioned, you need to remove the `<style> ... </style>` tag from the `<head>` tag and use the `<link>` tag directly inside of it.

#### 2. Not `id` but `class`

Your **HTML** and **CSS** have many errors. For example, you are styling in the **CSS** file:

```
.top left links {
    ...
}
```

Here `.top` is defined as a `class` but in your **HTML** code you defined it as an `id`, check this line:

```
<!-- Containing Top Left Links on Nav Bar -->
<div id="top left links">
...
</div>

<!--Containing Top Right Links on Nav Bar-->
<div id="top right links">
...
</div>
```

Remember that an `id` should be unique therefore you should change `id` attributes with `class` attributes.

#### 3. No white spaces

In your **CSS** file all your definitions are incorrect:

```
.top left links {
    ...
}
```

From this definition, we know that `.top` is a class, but `left` and `links` are representing tags. And we all know that where is no `<left>` nor `<links>` tags they should be represented as classes. Also, remember that you concatenate them when you want to refer to **a single element with multiple classes** and you separate classes by a white space when you want to refer to **a descendant element**.

So the correct definition will be without white spaces:

```
.top.left.links {
    ...
}
```

Finally, I did some modification on the **CSS** file for the `.search1` class. Check this code:

```css
/* Google Duplicate CSS */

.top.left.links {
  float: left;
  color: #718090;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top.left.links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top.right.links {
  float: right;
  color: #718090;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.top.right.links a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#ham_menu {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  float: right;
}

.search1 {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#f1f1f1));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #f1f1f1);
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  color: #5F6368;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 27px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 11px 4px;
  min-width: 54px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bottom.left.links,
.bottom.right.links {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #718090;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.bottom.left.links {
  float: left;
}

.bottom.right.links {
  float: right
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 980px;
  z-index: 103px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!--Header Menu of Page -->
<header>
  <!-- Containing Top Left Links on Nav Bar -->
  <div class="top left links">
    <a href="https://about.google/intl/en/?fg=1&utm_source=google-US&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=hp-header">About</a>
    <a href="https://store.google.com/?utm_source=hp_header&utm_medium=google_oo&utm_campaign=GS100042">Store</a>
  </div>

  <!--Containing Top Right Links on Nav Bar-->
  <div class="top right links">
    <li><a href="https://mail.google.com">Gmail</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi">Images</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/signinchooser?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin">Sign In</a></li>
  </div>

</header>
<!--Top Right Ham Menu-->
<img id="ham_menu" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png" class="right">

<!--Actual Google Image, Search Form, and Buttons-->
<center>
  <img src="http://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2019/us-teacher-appreciation-week-2019-begins-4994791740801024-2x.jpg" alt="Happy US Teacher Appreciation Week 2019!" class="center">
  <form class="search" input type="text"> </form>
  <button class="search1" type="submit" value="Google Search" style="visibility">
         Google Search
        </button>

  <button class="search1">
        I'm Feeling Lucky
        </button>

  <p><a href="https://www.blog.google/outreach-initiatives/education/teacher-appreciation-week-2019/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=taw_2019" target="_blank">We're supporting teachers inspiring the next generation.</a></p>
</center>



<!--Footer Links-->
<footer>
  <div class="bottom left links">
    <a href="https://ads.google.com/intl/en_us/home/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpafoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=google_hpafooter&fg=1">Advertising</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/services/?subid=ww-ww-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=google_hpbfooter&fg=1#?modal_active=none">Business</a>
  </div>

  <div class="bottom right links">
    <li><a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en&gl=us">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://policies.google.com/terms?hl=en&gl=us">Terms</a></li>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style tag from the beginning and end of the link tag, like the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="googleduplicate.css"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove the `<script>` tag so that you can reference this **CSS** file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add some context or more explanation about your answer. Also, read about [How to Answer a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write effective answers.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style tag from the beginning and end of the link tag, like the following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="googleduplicate.css"/>
```

**and in this condition make sure your HTML file and CSS file need to be in same folder.**

Answer (score 0):

`link` tag is used **directly inside** the `head` tag

It must be like this:

```
<head> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="googleduplicate.css"/>
</head>
```